# Writing autocomplete plugin for IDE's

Tags: plugins, ide, autocomplete

As of now , other than visual studio , and netbeans , very few IDE's have given me satisfactory auto complete(or code suggestion?) features. Yeah they do perform to an extent , but i would atleast like to try my hand at making one , that suits to my taste. 
I have experience in java , c , C++ , C# and have learnt the basics of wxwidgets(with the intention of writing a plugin for Code::Blocks) . But , where do i start with the basics of creating and writing plugins?

Comment: Good luck! That is a long and lonely road you are traveling on. Been there, done that... (+1 for inspiration)

Comment: first choose one IDE and learn how to write plugin for it.

Comment: i guess , my question is just too broad. What if i wanted to make one on CodeBlocks. Their support site has never helped me.